# can't set Form field Entity (Many to Many) as required

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, required

I have an Entity Invoice with a ManyToMany relation to Entity PaymentMethod

```
class Invoice
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\PaymentMethod")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="sf_invoices_paymentmethods")
     */
    protected $paymentMethods;
}
```

In my Invoice Form Type, i add this field with the following script :

```
->add('paymentMethods', 'entity', array(
        'label' => false,
        'class' => 'EvoBackendBundle:PaymentMethod',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('pm')
                ->where('pm.usedInInvoice = 1')
                ->orderBy('pm.position');
        },
        'property' => 'name',
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'required' => true,
    ))
```

And when I look at the source code generated by the form page, i can see there is no required="required" attribute in my paymentMethods checkboxes. Does anyone know why ?

How can I make sure at least 1 paymentMethod is checked (clients-side) and so that every invoice has at least 1 paymentMethod (Doctrine side)

I tried @ORM\JoinTable(name="sf_invoices_paymentmethods", nullable=false), but it throws an error.

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution.

added

```
'constraints' => array(
    new Count(array(
        'min' => 1,
        'minMessage' => 'At least 1 choice is required',
    )),
),
```

So my field in form type looks like this :

```
->add('paymentMethods', 'entity', array(
        'label' => false,
        'class' => 'EvoBackendBundle:PaymentMethod',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('pm')
                ->where('pm.usedInInvoice = 1')
                ->orderBy('pm.position');
        },
        'property' => 'name',
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'constraints' => array(
            new Count(array(
                'min' => 1,
                'minMessage' => 'At least 1 choice is required',
            )),
        ),
    ))
```

Answer (score -1):

Checkboxes let a user select ZERO or MORE options of a limited number of choices.This is not about symfony .This is a html question ,i think you must to do some javaScript code.

For the server side use [validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) ,in your case [choice validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html)

Comment: ok for the html side, i'll put some jquery validation on this. What about doctrine side ? In a ManyToMany relation, how can I force at least 1 entity to be selected ?

Comment: use [min option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html#min)

Comment: Where am I supposed to use this option ? In the form type ? In the entity property declaration ? My field type is set to "entity", looks like it doesn't accept "min" option.

Comment: No you must understand the use of [validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html)